# wolframscript creates tons of log files

Tags: streams, scripting, processlink

On Linux, wolframscript seems to create log files in .Mathematica/ApplicationData/ProcessLink/Streams

for example:

```
wolframscript -c SemanticImport[\"/path/to/file.csv\"] > /dev/null
```

generates files called `wl-stream-stderr-(nonce)` and `wl-stream-stdout-(nonce)`

I don't *think* the issue is only with SemanticImport, but that's certainly one that generates log files. (For example, `-c 2+2` does not generate a log file.)

After a few heavy days of wolframscripting, my hard drive runs out of space from all these log files.

The contents look something like this:

---

> STARTED: interactive mode
>
> READY
>
> Running with hints: {Delims: [], HeaderLines: 0, FixedSpaceTable: false, AutomaticTokenization: true, AutomaticHeader: true, MissingDataRules: map[MissingRuleType:ForAll Rules:[]], ColumnSpans: [],
>    ExcludedLines: [], AllowedDomains: [], ColumnCount: -1
>   LOADING: include [], exclude [PeopleData]
>   DONE LOADING
>
> SUCCESS: (etc.)

I can't find an option in `wolframscript` to turn off these log files. Other than just deleting all files in that directory every minute or so as a cron job, is there a more elegant or correct solution to keep the files from being created in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that adding `KillProcess/@Processes[]` fixes this problem.